# JPA2 Criteria: How to avoid a cross join using path.get()

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

If you have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bField", nullable = true)
    private B myBObject;

}
```

And I have a generic generator of Criteria who will do that:

```
Root<A> root = criteria.from(A.class);
root.get("myBObject").get("aFieldInB");
```

The problem is the following: the generated sql will contains a CROSS JOIN between A and B.
But I would like that the generated sql will contains a LEFT JOIN between A and B.

How can I do that?

Comment: try     Join<A, B> b = root.join("myBObject", JoinType.LEFT);

Comment: Of course I know that... but my criteria object is generated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: So any of you have found a solution to this problem? :/

Answer (score 3):

You must use a join().  In general it is better to always use a join() for relationships.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#JoinType

Comment: Yes I know. But as I said, I have a engine to generate my criteria. And this engine receives a Class object (Root) and a String of the path ("myBObject.aFieldInB"). The path cannot be predicted!